# Magento 2 - How to remove "Add New Customer" button in Index Admin Customer

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-options

How to remove "Add New Customer" in Index Admin Customer:
[image]

I created a new module: 
Create 2 file:
1) NameSpace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="customer_listing">
    </uiComponent>
</referenceContainer>
```

2) NameSpace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customer_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array" >
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Customer</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
                <item name="style" xsi:type="string">display:none</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="customer_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customer_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">customer_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected customers?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="subscribe">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">subscribe</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subscribe to Newsletter</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massSubscribe"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="unsubscribe">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">unsubscribe</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/massUnsubscribe"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to unsubscribe selected customers from newsletter?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">assign_to_group</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
................................
...................................
</listing>
```

When I removed "Add New Customer" by remove some code in this xml file:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">customer_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array" >
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Customer</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
                <item name="style" xsi:type="string">display:none</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

But it reused original core layout,Anyone know, show me pls!Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

to

```
 <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
 </item>
```

Comment: I tried but it not change anything .

Comment: Yes! I remove all content in :  <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
 </item> and paste : <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> then it worked ! Thanks @Arkadii Chyzhov !

Comment: I tried to remove  "company" field from checkout but had no success. Could you help?

                    `<item name="company" xsi:type="array">  
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">  
          <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>  
      </item>  </item>`

Answer (score 1):

Rename customer_listing.xml to customer_custom_listing.xml and also update the new filename in NameSpace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_index.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="customer_custom_listing">
    </uiComponent>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now you can delete the below lines from customer_custom_listing.xml to remove the button.

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array" >
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Customer</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
                <item name="style" xsi:type="string">display:none</item>
            </item>
        </item>
```

Comment: I tried to do this way, but it not remove button, and it generate button of  original layout.